# How can I use dynamic errors while retaining comparability for testing?

Tags: go, testing, error-handling

In go I often use

```
func MyFunc(s someInterface) error {
    err := OtherFunc(s)
    return fmt.Errorf("something wrong: %s", err)
}
```

So I lose the original error value, because I just take the error string and forge it into a new error. That is what I mean with dynamic errors.

Now consider a test for `MyFunc()`:

```
func TestMyFunc(t *testing.T) {
    s := mockSomeInterface()
    testErr := MyFunc(s)
    if testErr != interfaceSpecificErrorValue {
        t.Errorf("fail")
    }
}
```

What would I use for `interfaceSpecificErrorValue` (which is specific to `someInterface` in this example)? Or how could I make this testable?

I understand that I can solve this by defining all my possible errors beforehand and give them a constant value. What I am interested in is if there is another way to achieve this, because I like the hierarchical error messages that you can dynamically build up using `fmt.Errorf("...: %s, err)`. There must be a good way to keep the error hierarchy without losing the original value.

(Comparing the output of the `Error()` method is a possibility, but not a good one.)

Comment: May be https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/errors

Comment: Errors don't need to be strings. The standard library is full of error types that wrap other, underlying errors ([os.PathError](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#PathError) for instance). The package zerkms suggests is quick and easy to use, but I strongly suggest to create specific, useful types that let errors be *handled* and not only reported.

Comment: @Peter could you maybe give an example for a specific, useful type? I looked at os.PathError, it has an "Err error" field containing the "upstream" error. Is that what you suggest?

Comment: Yes. But it also has a Timeout method. In fact, [many types do](https://golang.org/search?q=Timeout#Methods) and there is also a common [Temporary method](https://golang.org/search?q=Temporary#Methods). They help callers decide whether it's worth retrying something.

Comment: To let errors be *handled* and not only reported is the kind of hint I needed. While the package proposed by zerkms is a good read certainly, I don't feel like I want to add this to my projects. Hopefully somebody will add an answer with a little code example for a good, specific error type with context, maybe I will come up with something later.

Answer (score 0):

My preliminary answer to this is: In Go currently there is no canonical way to achieve nested errors with comparable error values.

After reading the offical documents and blog posts on error handling again, quite some source code from standard libraries, and finally this proposal: https://github.com/golang/proposal/blob/master/design/go2draft-error-values-overview.md, I decided I will keep my error types simple and static and wait for Go 2 to offer a better way.